# Is there a term for the class of words that are not onomatopoeia / sound symbolic

Tags: terminology, sound-symbolism

I could call them non-sound-symbolic, but this isn't quite true since you could argue that all words have some degree of sound symbolism. Is there a term that determines the set of words that excludes "primarily sound symbolic" words like "boom", "ugh", and "kira-kira" (Japanese, to shine/glitter)?

Comment: Sound symbolism is completely different from, and much more common and general than, onomatopoeia. There is no term for precisely this set of English words. And "primarily sound-symbolic" is not a category but a judgement.

Comment: I'm under the assumption that onomatopoeia is a type of sound symbolic utterance. Is that more or less accurate? What sort of a category would you put iconic words in?

Comment: I agree that onomatopoeia are a subset of sound-symbolic words. Most linguistic theories assume Saussure's "arbitrariness of the signifier" to be the general case, and sound-symbolism to be the exception (though the extent of this "arbitrariness" has been questioned as of lately). So "not sound-symbolic" would be the common, unnamed case. If I had to talk about them, I'd use Sausurre's term "arbitrary" (though I live in a country where Sausurre is still taught, so everyone knows his terminology; I hear many English-speaking linguistic centres don't study his works anymore, so YMMV.)

Comment: Hmm maybe the term I'm looking for here is "iconic" vs "non-iconic" words

Comment: Re: categories: I'd prefer to define categories distributionally. So *kira-kira* is a sound-symbolic adverb, because it uses *-to* to modify a verb (*kirakira-to kagayaiteru*); whereas *shabu-shabu* is a sound-symbolic noun, because you say *shabu-shabu no*, *shabu-shabu wo*; and *chiguhagu* is a sound-symbolic na-adjective, since you say *chiguhagu na*. In the English *sl-* set, "slide" is a sound-symbolic verb, "slippery" adj, "slime" noun etc.

Comment: @RECURSIVEFARTS I guess "iconic" would work under Peircean semiotics. This may be preferable to Sausurre's "arbitrariness of the sign" if your linguistics audience is more familiar with Peircean terms than Saussurean ones.

Comment: That could refer to Peirce's "icon" category, but it could be general, too. In English simplex words, around half are sound-symbolic in one way or another (often several). For example, consider the [English `kl`-words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf).

Comment: You presuppose that this "class" even exists. I doubt one could call that a natural class, because these words have no distinguishable property besides not being onomatopoeic - just like there isn't a natural class of non-pharyngeal sounds or something either, because there is nothing that makes them homgenous. And if it doesn't form a class, then there's no need for a term for it.